# LaunchScreen.storyboard appear on first Time when app Run

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

`LaunchScreen.Storyboards` appears the first time the app is installed and after it no longer appears. In simulator it works correctly, the issue only happens on a read device.

Please let me know how to fix this issue so I can see LauchScreen everytime when the app launched. I am using Xcode 9.

Thanks

Comment: what is the compatibilty of your project is it only iPhone or universal?

Comment: if your app run in background it will not appear.

Comment: My App is iPad app